# Using Levenshtein function in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel 6.x and mysql is 5.0.12

I'm building simple text search engine in my app and below is my code.

```
return Collection::whereIn('type', $request->input('types'))
    ->whereRaw('levenshtein(?, `name`) BETWEEN  ? AND ?', [
        $request->input('name'), 0, 4
])->get();
```

.. It works fine. However, this is result of failure. It's not what I wanted at first.
What I originally wanted to do was select a value that I calculated with a user-defined function and sort the result by that value.

```
// something like this..?
$query = SELECT *, levenshtein(?, `name`) AS diff WHERE `type` like ? AND `diff` < 4 ORDER BY `diff` ASC;
```

I want the grammar to be a bit beyond the accuracy. Anyway, I put the following code to show that sentence.

```
return Collection::addSelect(
    DB::raw('levenshtein(?, `name`) as diff', [$request->input('name')])
)->havingBetween('diff', [0, 4])->get();
```

...Of course, didn't work. I was tried `whereBetween` at first and it didn't work. According to what I've read, alias name `diff` works after `where` clause, right? I tried a few different things, but it was the same.

What I want is to find the closest strings with the levenshtein function and list them in order of closest order. How can I do that??

---

edit 1try

```
return Collection::addSelect(
    DB::raw('levenshtein(?, `name`) as `diff`', [$request->input('name')])
)->havingBetween('diff', [0,4])->get();
```

Above 3rd code, it returns an error that

```
select levenshtein(0, `name`) as `diff` from `collections` having `diff` between 4 and ?)
// and as far as I understand, my code have to generate
select levenshtein('input text', `name`) as `diff` from `collections` having `diff` between 0 and 4)
```

..is that something I didn't catch? or its really a bug??

Comment: Is Collection here an eloquent model or Laravel Collection?

Comment: oh, its Model ! and I partially solve the problem but thinking that it is a bug or not..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

..solve!

Its my wrong that using `DB::raw` inside and also put at this wrong parameter.

```
return Collection::selectRaw('*, levenshtein(?, `name`) as `diff`', [$request->input('name')])
    ->havingBetween('diff', [0,4])->get();
```

This works find and I notice that order of binding parameter is probably closed at some years ago.

Anyway, solve!

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Is there something extra to do for SQL injection, or would this already be safe because it goes through the $request object?

Comment: Oh, sry to late. The code of mine was very early stage at that time, so I didn't care about injection and possible other problems on that moment.

.... and I didn't fix that problem so my personal page have been used as a gateway for hackers! loll

Answer (score -1):

PHP has standart function levenshtein($record, $searchTerm);

```
// Calculate Levenshtein distance for each record
$results = $names->whereNotIn('id', [$excludeId])
    ->filter(function ($record) use ($searchTerm) {
        $levenshteinDistance = levenshtein($record->name, $searchTerm);
        $record->levenshteinDistance = $levenshteinDistance;
        return $levenshteinDistance < 4; // Adjust the threshold as needed
});
```